# Get rows of Last hour, Last 'x' minutes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2019-express

| Order ID | Picker ID | Time_Picked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 2020-01-13 11:28:00 |
| 2 | 222 | 2020-01-13 11:40:00 |
| 3 | 333 | 2020-01-13 10:00:00 |
| 4 | 444 | 2020-01-13 9:00:00 |
| 5 | 555 | 2020-01-13 9:45:00 |

```
SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE Time_picked BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

I am getting a blank output in my SQL Server 2016.

Considering time now is 12:00 PM. I want to return the first two rows (last hour rows).

Please help me with a function to find details of last 'x' minutes if there is any as well.

PS: I am regularly accessing this data from SQL Server and I am trying for it to be dynamic.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a date without time is treated as if it were at time 00:00:00.000000, so if the current time is  09:23:45 you deduct 1 hour to 08:23:45 then ask for data that is between 08:23:45 and 00:00:00 it won't work as the first value must be less than the second value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your time expression is:

```
WHERE Time_picked BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Under most circumstances, the first will be *larger* then the second, because the `CAST()` removes the time component.  I suspect you want:

```
WHERE Time_picked BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Or assuming that all time values are in the past:

```
WHERE Time_picked >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I tried the first two expressions, they still give me a blank output.
Can you please explain how the third expression works?